# useLocation().pathname in react-router-dom is changing, but when I put it in an if statement, it keeps saying true

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-router-dom

I'm making a react app. I'm importing useLocation and putting it into a variable (location). I'm checking if pathname is NOT "/" it should output false, but it keeps saying true in every page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Header() {
  const [inIndex, setInIndex] = useState();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    //Checks if location.pathname is not "/".
    if (location.pathname !== "/") setInIndex(false);
    else setInIndex(true);
  }, []);

  console.log(inIndex); //Keeps saying true

  return null;
}

export default Header;
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I also checked what location.pathname is and it's "/" and it's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried subscribing for change in `location.pathname` in your hook?:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //Checks if location.pathname is not "/".
    setInIndex(location.pathname === "/")
  }, [location.pathname]);
```

P.S. You don't really need the if statement, as it calculates into regular `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

It only ever computes once, when the component mounts, because of the empty dependency array. If you add `location` to the effect's dependency array it will trigger the callback when `location` changes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Header() {
  const [inIndex, setInIndex] = useState();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    //Checks if location.pathname is not "/".
    if (location.pathname !== "/") setInIndex(false);
    else setInIndex(true);
  }, [location]); // <-- add location to dependency array

  console.log(inIndex); //Keeps saying true

  return null;
}

export default Header;
```

**Note:** You can also just save *the inverse* of the original conditional test, since you set false when the condition is true.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Checks if location.pathname is not "/".
  setInIndex(location.pathname === "/");
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Actually the condition must be `===` instead of `!==`